# Can I decode authorization code similar to the way I see what is inside a Bearer token?

Tags: oauth-2.0

There are many online tools that show the calims inside a Bearer token.

Is there any way or tool to see what is inside an authorization code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because there is no data in authorization code. It is just some random value generated by Authorization server.